# Create Association in Sequelize to do a Left Join

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to do a left join using Sequelize that does the same as this SQL code.

`SELECT * FROM events LEFT JOIN zones ON event_tz=zid WHERE event_creator_fk=116;`

I have two tables: `events` and `zones` (with a list of time zones).

When querying for all the events that are created by a specific user, I also want to get the name of the time zone and other details about the TZ.

I have tried many combinations of solutions by reviewing sample code, other Stack Overflow questions and the documentation as best I can.  The query always works, but doesn't do any joins.  That is, it below code always returns the list of events, but no time zone data from the `zones` table.  The generated SQL is correct, except it doesn't have the `...LEFT JOIN zones ON event_tz=zid...` part.

*The below code is wrong. See answers for details.*

```
db.Event.findAll(
    { where: { event_creator_fk: someUserID } },
    { include: [{ model: db.Zone } ]}
);
```

If I understand correctly, adding associations between tables in sequelize results in an additional column from automatically being created.  This is not what I want to do. I do not want Sequelize to modify the tables or database in any way. I want to setup my database and it's tables without Sequelize. Therefore, I am not calling `sequelize.sync()`.  I don't know if there is away to setup associations the way I want.

**Model Definitions**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Event = sequelize.define('Event', {

            eid: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            event_tz: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                references: "Zone",
                referencesKey: "zid"
            },
        }, {
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    return models.Event.hasOne(models.Zone);
                }
            },
            freezeTableName: true,
            timestamps: false,
            tableName: 'events'
        }
    );
    return Event;
};


module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Zone', {
        zid: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                return models.Zone.belongsTo(models.Event);
            }
        },
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'zones'
    });
};
```

**Table Definitions**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zones;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zones (
    zid integer NOT NULL,
    country_code character(2) NOT NULL,
    zone_name text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (zid)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    eid                             BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    event_tz                        SERIAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eid),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_tz) 
        REFERENCES zones(zid) MATCH FULL ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the associations and tell sequelize about your foreign key. belongsTo means 'add the fk to this model':

```
models.Event.belongsTo(models.Zone, { foreignKey: 'event_tz');

models.Zone.hasOne(models.Event, { foreignKey: 'event_tz');
// or hasMany if this is 1:m
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried your solution with both `.hasOne` and `.hasMany`, but it still isn't working.  I don't get any errors, results are returned for the Events table, but I still get the Zone ID.  Do I need this code as specified in the above model definitions: `references: "Zone", referencesKey: "zid"`.

Comment: What I don't understand: Is it necessary to call `sequelize.sync()`.  I don't want sequelize to modify my tables.

Comment: You don't need to call sequelize.sync - that is only needed if you want't sequelize to create your tables.

Comment: If your model still have a zoneId column, you must not be specifying the foreign key correctly

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem was that I was using the `findAll` method incorrectly.  The query options `where` and `include` should have been included as part of the same object.  The first parameter to `findAll` is an options parameter. See [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/) for more details.  The correct code should look like the following.

```
db.Event.findAll(
    {
         where: { event_creator_fk: someUserID },
         include: [{ model: db.Zone } ]
    },
);
```